# Activity.this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

Well, the question is something which is similar to already asked questions on the forum but I couldn't find a suitable answer to my problem.My usersettingactivity class-

```
public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements View.OnClickListener,
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();
    PreferenceCategory langCategory=(PreferenceCategory)findPreference("change_lang");
    if(PrefSettings.getInstance().getUserCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("NA"))
        screen.removePreference(langCategory);
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.user_preference_layout, root, true);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavIconClickListener(this);

    TextView version = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.build_version);
    version.setText("v" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    AppTracker.btnClicked(key);
    if ("prefNotification".equals(key)) {
        Utils.configureServiceAlarm(this);
    }
}

public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {
        if (preference.getKey().contains("whitelist_paths")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), FolderChooserActivity.class));
        }
        if(preference.getKey().contains("change_language"))

            LanguageDialog languageDialog=new LanguageDialog(UserSettingActivity.this); //Here is the problem

        languageDialog.langDialogFragment();
        return true;
    }
}}
```

My LanguageDialog class-

```
public class LanguageDialog {
private Activity a = null;
HashMap<String, String> lang;

public LanguageDialog(Activity activity){
    a=activity;
}

public void langDialogFragment()
{


    lang = new HashMap<String, String>();
    lang.put("English","en");
    lang.put("Bengali","bn");
    lang.put("Hindi","hi");
    lang.put("Kannada","kn");
    lang.put("Marathi","mr");
    lang.put("Tamil","ta");
    lang.put("Telugu","te");
    final CharSequence[] inlang = {"English","Hindi","Bengali","Kannada","Marathi","Tamil","Telugu"};


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(a, R.style.AlertDialog));
    builder.setTitle(R.string.select_language)
            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setSingleChoiceItems(inlang, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String lang_code=lang.get(inlang[which].toString());
                    Logger.d(inlang[which].toString());
                    updateLocale(lang_code);


                }

            })
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Utils.navigateToActivity(a);
                    a.finish();
                }
            })

            .show();

}

public void updateLocale(String lang)
{
    Locale locale;
    if(lang.equalsIgnoreCase("en")) {
        locale = new Locale(lang,"US");
        PrefSettings.getInstance().setUserlanguage(lang);
    }
    else {
        locale = new Locale(lang,"IN");
        PrefSettings.getInstance().setUserlanguage(lang);
    }
    Logger.d(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = a.getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.locale = locale;
    a.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            a.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


} }
```

The problem is occurring in the UserSettingActivity where I am not able to create a object of LanguageDialog in the fragment class. It is showing the error -
UserSettingActivity cannot be referenced from a static context. I have already tried all the possible answers to the questions similar to this problem but none could help me out.Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: use `getActivity()`.

Comment: Not working. It gives me an error- Not a statement.

Comment: it should work. post what changes you have made

Comment: @Override
  public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {
   if (preference.getKey().contains("whitelist_paths")) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), FolderChooserActivity.class));
   }
   if(preference.getKey().contains("change_language"))

    LanguageDialog languageDialog=new LanguageDialog(getActivity());

   languageDialog.langDialogFragment();
   return true;
  }

Comment: The method I have posted is the last method of the inner fragment class.

Comment: getActivity gives the context of activity. i tried your code LangiageDialog and i don't get your error especially when this `startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), FolderChooserActivity.class));` works in your code itself

Comment: But its not working!

Comment: The problem is in the statement-LanguageDialog languageDialog=new LanguageDialog(UserSettingActivity.this);

   languageDialog.langDialogFragment();

Comment: http://imgur.com/xgSOmzV

Comment: what about braces for if statement. the ide gives you an hint. put braces properly

Comment: I am going to kill myself for this a silly mistake. Thank you Raghunandan. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

You can try getActivity() instead of using .this

Comment: Using getActivity() gives me an error - Not a Statement.

Comment: But you are already using getActivity() in this line      startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), FolderChooserActivity.class));

Answer (score 1):

your 
MyPreferenceFragment is static, you cannot refer a non- static class from static fragment
`public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment` remove static from here

Comment: Is there a way that I continue to use static and my problem gets solved?

Comment: And on removing static, it gives me an error- This fragment Inner class should be static.

Comment: can you make the fragment class separate and try to initialize in the activity